# Matlab: Re-label default x-ticks

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

In a Matlab plot I define my x-axis as a preaccumulated array `timeInSec`:

```
y = data;
x = timeInSec;
plot(x , y);
```

The generated x-axis on the plot looks like this:

[image]

The ticks and tick-values (the `0`, `0.5`, `1`, `1.5`, `2` and `2.5`) here are auto-generated by Matlab. And I am happy with them.

But now I would like to change the tick-value labels customly. Something like:

```
timeInHrMin = datestr(tickValues, 'HH:MM')
xticklabels(timeInHrMin)
```

But how do I grab all shown `tickValues`? I need them to remain auto-generated. So I must in some way grab only those shown (the `0`, `0.5`, `1`, `1.5`, `2` and `2.5`) and relabel them with `xticklabels`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can grab all shown tick values either by using `get(gca,'XTick')` as was suggested by Sardar Usama or by accessing property `CurrentAxes.XTick` of your figure.

As for relabeling, there is one small yet important/annoying detail regarding using `xticklabels`. Once you use it, ticks are no longer automatically generated. In order to solve it you can use `xtick('auto')` just before grabbing and modifying the labels.

I'm also guessing that you want to have the ticks refreshed when you zoom in/out. You can do it using `zoom` and its callbacks.

Code below should make it all clear:

```
function so
    % meaningless data to have some ticks
    fs = 48000;
    t = 5;
    tvect = 0:1/fs:t-1/fs;
    a = sin(2*pi*tvect);

    % plotting data
    fig = figure;
    plot(tvect, a)

    % modifying the ticks for the first time after creating the plot
    mypostcallback(fig, struct('Axes', fig.CurrentAxes));

    % modifying post zoom callback
    h = zoom(fig);
    h.ActionPostCallback = @mypostcallback;
end

function mypostcallback(obj,evd)
    % turning on auto generation of ticks after previous usage of xticklabels
    xticks('auto')
    % part where you modify tick labels however you want. 
    % In my case simply adding 10 to the original values.
    xticklabels(evd.Axes.XTick + 10)  
end
```